# how to rectify the validation_errors(); function's error message in password field?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am learning **codeigniter 3**(pursuing **Edwin Diaz's CI Course** and i am coding a **login system**. I have two controller methods called **index** and **login** . I am using **form_validation library** for this. But my problem lies in showing error messages in the **password field** . it is always showing the error message **The Password field is required.**even if i submit password. I am pasting the code below :

```
public function login(){
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Username','trim|required|min_length[3]');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|min_length[3]');

 if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

 $data = array('errors'=> validation_errors() );
   $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
    redirect('home/index');

 }
 else{

 }
```

here is **login_view.php** code

```
    <h1>Login Form</h1>

<?php $attributes= array('id' =>'login_form' ,'class'=>'form-horizontal' ); ?>
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('errors'):?>
      <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('errors');?>
 <?php endif; ?>

<?php echo form_open('home/login',$attributes);?>
    <?php echo form_label("Username") ;?>
    <div class="form-group">
    <?php $data = array('class'=>'form-control','name'=>'name','placeholder'=>'enter username');?>
    <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
</div>

    <?php echo form_label("Password") ;?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php $data = array('class'=>'form-control','password'=>'password','placeholder'=>'enter password');?>
    <?php echo form_password($data); ?>
</div>
<?php 
$data = array('class'=>'btn btn-primary','name'=>'submit','value'=>'login');?>
    <?php echo form_submit($data); ?>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

can anyone please say why the password field is doing these and how to rectify this ?

**P.S** :Many are saying codeigniter 3 does not support php version 7.3.12 while the same code is 
running perfectly on php version 7.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you haven't set the name for your password input.

> HINT: View your HTML Source Code via your web browser to see what was
>   generated. This always gives you a good clue as to what's not working.

So you need to change `'password'=> 'password'` to `'name'=>'password`

Your original line

```
<?php $data = array('class'=>'form-control','password'=>'password','placeholder'=>'enter password');?>
```

Should become

```
<?php $data = array('class'=>'form-control','name'=>'password','placeholder'=>'enter password');?>
```